# Can you get another Boss Soul by respawning bosses with a Bonfire Ascetic?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2 I believe you can respawn bosses with a Bonfire Ascetic. This made me wonder if you respawn them and kill them again, do you get the Boss Soul again?

Comment: it is good practice to wait to accept answers. This way you do not accidentally accept wrong answers. It also encourages more people to write good answers.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178124/what-bonfires-should-i-burn-ascetics-in-to-get-ng-items-or-higher) about Bonfire Ascetics should also clear up any confusion :)

Answer (score 22):

Yes. Ascetics respawn bosses and they will drop their boss soul. (At one point this was a speed run technique)

They can also drop items from higher playthroughs. For example, you can use an ascetic in your first playthrough on the [Skeleton Lord's](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/The+Skeleton+Lords) bonfire in order to defeat them again and get the clear bluestone ring +2, which is normally only available in NG+

In fact, one of the most efficient soul farming strategies is to use ascetics to respawn and fight the Giant Lord.

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic

> Also, bonfire intensity caps at 99, but you can still burn ascetics
>   past 99 to respawn the boss

Comment: Some bosses, like the Rotten, also drop an additional soul. The Rotten for example drop Old Dead One Soul.

Comment: @RichardA All of the Primal Bosses (Lost Sinner, Old Iron King, Freja and The Rotten) drop an "Old One's" Soul. These are 'fragments' of the original four Great One's from DkS1 (Bed of Chaos, Gwyn, Seath and Nito)

Comment: It is also important to note that difficulty will cap well before intensity 99. There still is some speculation on exactly where it is, but it's considered somewhere between intensity 7-11

Comment: @Ben The difficulty soft caps at Bonfire Intensity 8, which is equivalent to NG+7. After Bonfire Intensity 8 the game doesn't get harder anymore. Also, using a Bonfire Ascetic will make the difficulty carry over to the next playthrough; using a Bonfire Ascetic on a bonfire in NG, will cause the Bonfire Intensity to be 3 in NG+ making it equivalent to NG+2.