# Do bosses respawn in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

[Close to all common enemies respawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404182/do-all-standard-enemies-respawn), but so far I haven't encountered a boss that reappears, mini-bosses included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In conjunction with [zero298's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270325/73976), a "boss" enemy is any enemy that has a static, on-screen health bar. These bosses will only spawn once per new game. Only entering a new game+ will allow them to respawn. However, if you wish to face them again before entering ng+, you can use the White Sign Soapstone and assist other players in defeating them.

These enemies are: (in general order of encounter)

**Area Bosses:** Once these bosses are defeated, you cannot summon/be invaded in this area anymore.

- [Asylum Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/asylum-demon)
- [Taurus Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/taurus-demon)
- [Bell Gargoyles](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/bell-gargoyles)
- [Capra Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/capra-demon)
- [Gaping Dragon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gaping-dragon)
- [Chaos Witch Quelaag](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/chaos-witch-quelaag)
- [Iron Golem](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/iron-golem)
- [Dragon Slayer Ornstein](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/dragon-slayer-ornstein-executioner-smough) & [Executioner Smough](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/dragon-slayer-ornstein-executioner-smough)
- [Cross-Breed Priscilla](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/crossbreed-priscilla)
- [Ceaseless Discharge](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/ceaseless-discharge)
- [Demon Firesage](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/demon-firesage)
- [Centipede Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/centipede-demon)
- [Bed of Chaos](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/the-bed-of-chaos)
- [Seath the Scaleless](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/seath-the-scaleless)
- [Sif, The Great Grey Wolf](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sif-the-great-grey-wolf)
- [The Four Kings](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/the-four-kings)
- [Pinwheel](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/pinwheel)
- [Gravelord Nito](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gravelord-nito)
- [Gwyn, Lord of Cinder](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gwyn-lord-of-cinder)

**Optional Bosses:** defeating these do not affect summoning/invasions (with the exception of the Undead Asylum; since you have already defeated the area boss before invasions/summoning became available). This means if you wish to summon help for these fights, you will need to do so *before* fighting the main boss.

- [Stray Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/stray-demon)
- [Moonlight Butterfly](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/moonlight-butterfly)
- [Dark Sun Gwyndolin](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/dark-sun-gwyndolin)

**DLC Bosses:**

- [Sanctuary Guardian](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sanctuary-guardian)
- [Knight Artorias](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/knight-artorias)
- [Manus, Father of the Abyss](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/manus-father-of-the-abyss)
- [Black Dragon Kalameet](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/black-dragon-kalameet) (Kalameet is on optional Boss for the DLC)

---

There are also a series of enemies throughout the game that are not really considered "bosses" (sometimes referred to as "mini-bosses"), that will only spawn once per new game:

- [Black Knights](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/black-knight) (they do re-spawn in the Kiln of the First Flame)
- [Hellkite Dragon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/hellkite-dragon)
- [Hydra (Darkroot Basin/Ash Lake)](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/hydra)
- [Havel the Rock](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/havel-the-rock)
- [Armoured Tusk](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/armored-tusk)
- [Butcher](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/butcher)
- [Golden Crystal Golem](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/golden-crystal-golem)
- [Giant Undead Rat](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/giant-undead-rat)
- [Parasitic Wall Hugger](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/parasitic-wall-hugger)
- [Undead Dragon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-dragon)
- [Undead Prince Ricard](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-prince-ricard)
- [Prowling Demon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/prowling-demon)

Comment: Not exactly related to the OP; but in Dark Souls 2, the inclusion of [Bonfire Acsetics](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic) allows you to challenge enemies over and over again, in one playthrough

Comment: this only works in NG+ tho and not in NG

Comment: @XtremeBaumer what only works in ng+?

Comment: the Bonfire Ascetics. i am currently in my NG+ run in DS2 and there i was able to respawn the first Dragonrider, while i was not able to respawn the Giant Lord in my NG run (wanted to test the soul farming technique)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you have to use the appropriate bonfire. Bosses are linked to the nearest bonfire. There is nothing stopping you from doing this on NG, and I have personally done this any times

Comment: @XtremeBaumer [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/189017/73976) covers the same topic.

Comment: i burned one in the bonfire behind the door which leads to the last memory of a giant (where the boss is, like half a minute of walking) and it didn't respawn after completing the memory completly (not teleporting out)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this is *very* different to anything I have experienced before. I'd say something is not working properly, or there is a difference in the game somehow. Are you playing SotFS?

Comment: yes its SotFS. my game is bugged as hell anyways. can't play it in full screen because its causing a visual bug where you can't see anything. reinstalling, updating graphics driver etc didn' help lol

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'd say that might be part of your issue then. I suggest asking a question about it, hopefully someone might help you sort it out :)

Answer (score 5):

Bosses will respawn after you beat the game and move to New Game+. They will of course also be stronger. So will all enemies.

If you just want to fight the boss again, you could lay down your soap sign and wait to get summoned. You will not receive another boss soul on victory though.

Comment: But not during the current campaign?

Comment: @user598527 no, not during your current game. See my edit about summoning though.

Comment: I read that mini-bosses respawn "once per game": http://darksouls.wikidot.com/bosses   
Does that mean that they will respawn after closing the game? It is said in the same guide that "the major bosses can only be killed once per playthrough".

Comment: @user598527 where does it say they respawn? There are only 2 instances of the word "respawn" on that page and they are preceded by "don't". The very first bullet under mini-bosses says that all but a specific few only spawn once.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to respawn the dragon rider in Heide's Tower Of flame by using the  Bonfire Ascetic it makes him stronger so say ur in NG and u spawn him he will be NG+1 difficulty so on so fourth.
    Or gave me his souls and everything 
Just make sure u use the item in the first ever bonfire u see aka right next to the first old knight idk about others yet

Comment: Note that this question is asking about Dark Souls 1, but the bonfire ascetic is an item in Dark Souls 2.